# Input box to search for userform record and then delete from worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba

trying to figure out an easy way for when someone needs to delete their record from userform data in a spreadsheet. ideally, I want to have the user open up the userform, click `delete entry` and then an input box would pop up for them to type in their user ID and then the userform would search for that row in the table and delete the entry.

here is a shell of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub deleteData(rngColumn As Range, strSelector As String)

Dim rngCell As Range
Dim rngToDelete As Range
Set strSelector = InputBox("Enter Employee ID")
Set rngColumn = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Columns(3)

For Each rngCell In rngColumn
    If rngCell.Value = strSelector Then
        If rngToDelete Is Nothing Then
            Set rngToDelete = rngCell
        Else
            Set rngToDelete = Union(rngToDelete, rngCell)
        End If
    End If
Next

If Not rngToDelete Is Nothing Then
    rngToDelete.EntireRow.Select
End If

End Sub
```

But it's not doing anything when I try to click the button

Comment: If you're not passing any arguments to that sub then why does it have parameters?  Seems like they should instead be declared as variables in the sub.

Comment: Have you debugged the code? Is it called at all? Why has the routine parameters if you don't use them at all? Is it working if you execute it manually? If it is executed: Is the content of the cells within the range exactly the same as what the user enters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple code to find a user's input and delete the row.
To add the macro, double-clicking on the `UserForm` button in design mode will automatically create the `Click` event. Insert this code in the code window.

```
    'Assign the worksheet variable
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")

    'Assign the InputBox search string variable
    Dim srchID As String: srchID = InputBox("Enter Employee ID")

    'Assign a range variable to the cell where the search string is found
    Dim trgtCel As Range: Set trgtCel = ws.Range("C:C").Find(What:=srchID, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

        'Delete the trgtCel row containing the Employee's Information
        trgtCel.EntireRow.Delete
```